# SWT Invalid Thread Access on Mac OSX (Eclipse Helios)

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I have the simplest of all simple SWT programs (it doesn't even display hello world yet):

```
package com.samples.swt.first;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

When I run this on Mac OSX from Eclipse Helios, I get the following error:

> ***WARNING: Display must be created on main thread due to Cocoa restrictions.
>   Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException:
>   Invalid thread access     at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4282)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4197)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4168)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1065)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:822)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:805)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.(Device.java:130)   at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.(Display.java:696)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.(Display.java:687)  at
>   com.samples.swt.first.Main.main(Main.java:8)

As far as I can tell, I am doing everything correctly. Why am I getting this error? It says that `Display` must be created on the main thread, and as far as I can tell it is being created on the main thread. It then goes on to talk about `Exception in thread "main"`...

**EDIT:**

The error is gone now, I switched from using `swt-debug.jar` to `swt.jar`. If anybody knows why the debug jar causes this error I would love to know...

Answer (score 19):

You need to have the `-XstartOnFirstThread` switch when starting the application. This [question](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#carbonapp) on the SWT FAQ explains the reasons.