# swt app gets SWTException: Invalid thread access when executed from jar

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I wrote an swt app which runs great inside eclipse. I know about `Display.getDefault().asyncExec()`. That is definitely not the problem. After packing into a jar and calling `java -cp myjar.jar myclass`, I get:

> SWTException: Invalid thread access.

How can this be that it runs fine inside eclipse by not from jar?

Comment: We can't possibly say without seeing the code.

Comment: Can you give us *any* details at all to work off of?

Comment: Are you executing it from OSX?

Comment: osx yes. has nothing to do with specific code. take this tutorial, http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/UsingBusyIndicator.htm. it runs in eclipse but not by iteself from macbook command line.

Comment: @emish89. thanks for the hint. the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7904388/swt-invalid-thread-access-on-mac-osx-eclipse-helios